# error from template tags: 'str' object has no attribute 'as_widget'

Tags: python, django, templatetags

I made a template tag and when I am using that in my template I get this error:

> 'str' object has no attribute 'as_widget'

This is the code of my template tag:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()
@register.filter
def field_type(bound_field):
    return bound_field.field.widget.__class__.__name__


@register.filter
def input_class(bound_field):
    css_class = ''
    if bound_field.form.is_bound:
        if bound_field.errors:
            css_class = 'is-invalid'
        elif field_type(bound_field) != 'PasswordInput':
            css_class = 'is-valid'
    return 'form-control {}'.format(css_class)
```

and my template is here:

```
{% extends 'board/account.html' %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% load form_tags %}
{% block title %}Sign up{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<div class="accountform">
    <form method="POST">
        <h4 class="display-6 text-white p-3">Create your account</h4>
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="alert alert-danger p-0" style="border:none;">
            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
            {% for error in field.errors %}
            <span class="err">{{ error }}</span><br>
            {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="id_username">Username</label>
            {% render_field form.username|input_class class='form-control' placeholder='John Doe' %}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="id_email">Email</label>
            {% render_field form.email|input_class class='form-control' placeholder='johndoe@email.com' %}
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="id_password1">Password</label>
                {% render_field form.password1|input_class class='form-control' placeholder='****' %}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="id_password2">Confirm Password</label>
                {% render_field form.password2|input_class class='form-control' placeholder='****' %}
            </div>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Sign up" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
        <p class="display-6 bg-signup p-3">Have an account <a href="{% url 'signin' %}">Sign In</a></p>
    </form>
</div>

</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

I saw similar question and approved answer in SO which basically says that the solution for this issue is to add form in context, well that is already added, here is views

```
def signup_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('board:home')
    form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

Please help me solve this issue. Thank you for your help.

Comment: But your `input_class` filter takes the bound field and returns a string, which you're then passing to `render_field` which is expecting an actual field. Why are you doing this? What's the point of `input_class`?

Comment: I want to add `from-control is_invalid` CSS class if bound field has error, but if bound field has no errors I want to add `form-control is_valid` CSS class.

Comment: But you still need to pass the actual field to `render_field`.

Comment: sorry sir, I just started learning these template tags.

Comment: and I didn't understand the meaning of your last comment, if you kindly elaborate it for me (Django beginner)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any reason for either of these template tags. django-widget-tweaks already has the ability to [add a custom error class with `render_field`](https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks#render_field), and you already know when you're rendering the password field so you can add that class when you need to.

(Also, django-widget-tweaks provides the [`field_type` filter](https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks#field_type-and-widget_type) already).

So:

```
{% with WIDGET_ERROR_CLASS='my_error' %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="id_username">Username</label>
        {% render_field form.username class+='form-control' placeholder='John Doe' %}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="id_email">Email</label>
        {% render_field form.email class+='form-control' placeholder='johndoe@email.com' %}
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="id_password1">Password</label>
            {% render_field form.password1| class+='form-control' placeholder='****' %}
        </div>

    ...

{% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong way you have to add `calss` in class attribute not render class name as field. Do it like this.

```
{% render_field form.username class=form.username|input_class placeholder='John Doe' %}
```

Comment: why I should add extra `add:form.username` again?

Comment: Because 1) you have to pass `form.username` to `input_class` as parameter 2) You are using `form-control` class also you have to concatenate dynamic class with it. `add` will do it. So the result of expression `'form-control '|add:form.username|input_class` will be `form-control form-control <css_class>`. I think you should omit add as you are returning `from-control` from template tag also. See my edit.

Comment: I tried this solution before; I mused that it will add those classes, but it is not adding any class to those input elements. All it does is that it disappears that error.

Comment: Then error must be somewhere else. I suggest you to debug your code using pycharm or something similar and follow the documentation for third party packages carefully.